# "sh: line 1: Moved: command not found" installing npm with curl | sh

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, shell, curl

I attempted to install `npm` on mac OSX Yosemite with the command:

```sh
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

And I received the following message:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    51  100    51    0     0    296      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   298

sh: line 1: Moved: command not found
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Clearly, your response is not a shell script, but is a message starting with the word "Moved". When the shell tries to treat it as a script, you get that error.

Comment: Running `curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh`, with no `| sh` on the end, will make this clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing the curl `-L` option to follow redirects. However, you don't need to use this installation method anymore, npm comes with node and if your distro happens to split node's components up, npm is usually available as a separate package from one of your distro's repositories.

Comment: Just want to echo this: if you have a safer alternative to using the curl | sh pattern, it's a really good idea to use it. curl | sh can be made safe, but it can be challenging to defend: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/12/12/security-spectrum-curl-sh/?utm_source=stackoverflow-ao&utm_campaign=security-spectrum-curl-sh&utm_medium=referral

Answer (score 2):

I had to figure out where my node application was installed and add that to path.  I used the first method listed here:
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814
so turns out "node" was in /home/myname/node-latest-install/~/local/bin.

Adding that to PATH, then doing 
curl -L https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
worked for me.